# Mobile Top Menu drop downs not working

Tags: menu, rwd, magento1.9.3.1

The mobile menu on this site **nightskysecrets.com.au** is not dropping down.

Not sure if this is an upgrade issue but can't find the problem in css wondering if it is a Javascript issue.